# Spring Boot - cache not working, how to set cache up correctly?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My application is on Spring boot 1.5.1

I have looked up all common problems related to caching not working in spring boot (calling a cacheable method from the same class, etc) and I still can't seem to pinpoint why my method is not cacheing. I am just trying to use the simple cache built into Spring (ie the concurrent hashmap).

Setup: in pom.xml I added this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My configuration class is the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

I have a controller class that has the following method to get a list of versions.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getVersionList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public JSONObject getVersionList() {
    JSONObject retJSON = new JSONObject();
    List<String> versions = fetchVersionService.getVersionList();
    retJSON.put("versions", versions);
    return retJSON;
}
```

And the FetchVersionService class where I have the cacheable method to cache this versions list

```
@Cacheable("versions")
public List<String> getVersionList() {
    System.out.println("If there is something in the cache, it should not hit here.");
    return randomService.getVersions(); //another service class that gets versions from a remote location, which takes a long time
}
```

Whenever I make multiple GET calls to this function, it always goes inside the function even though I only expect to it execute the function once. For some reason it isn't cacheing the results. 
Any ideas where I went wrong with my setup? Thanks a lot.

Comment: see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial - where is your CacheManager defined?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I didn't explicitly define a CacheManager. My understanding is in Spring Boot with `@EnableCaching`, if no CacheManager is found Spring Boot automatically sets one up for you. However I tried to define my own, still not working - https://codeboje.de/caching-spring-boot/

Comment: Your code seems correct. More details of code can help to find out out mistake. Some things that I can think of is :  1.) check your imports . 2.) Bean scope

Comment: I imported the wrong package. Thank you so much for pointing that out, can't believe that was the issue.

Comment: @irfanhasan what package was wrong? I have the same issue

Comment: In my case the problem was that I was calling the method annotated with `@Cacheable` within the same class and this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 10):

In the comments under this question @irfanhasan mentions that they had imported the wrong package but there was no certain response.
I faced the same problem. I tried to use @Cachable annotation but it wasn't work. I found that it was imported as:

```
import springfox.documentation.annotations.Cacheable
```

Instead of:

```
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
```

Look carefully for your IDE imports.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments under this question, @irfanhasan mentions that they had imported the wrong package and @xetra11 replied asking which package was wrong which there was no reply to. I am not @irfanhasan but it might have been the following mixup: "You can also use the standard JSR-107 (JCache) annotations (such as @CacheResult) transparently. However, we strongly advise you to not mix and match the Spring Cache and JCache annotations."

Answer (score 0):

Below is an End to end working code to show case Caching implementation using SpringBoot.

```
@Cacheable("movies")
  public List<String> getMoviesList() {
   //logic to fetch movies using API call over webClient
  return moviesList;
}
```

Now this code makes the response of getMoviesList cacheable due to annotation `@Cacheable("movies")`
However this is not enough, as it needs bean of `CacheManager` as well.
In SpringBoot this is simplified, so all you need is `@EnableCaching`
This annotation can go in your main class with `@SpringBootApplication` as shown below

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
@EnableCaching
public class MoviesApplication {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MoviesApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Now depending on your business workflow, you can decide the cache eviction policy.

```
@CacheEvict(value = "movies", allEntries = true)
  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 12, timeUnit = TimeUnit.HOURS)
  public void evictMoviesFromCache() {
    // Nothing to do. Annotations cover functionality
    log.info("Evicting Movies from cache.");
  }
```

Above code evicts the code at scheduled interval of 12 hrs.

Alternatively, you could evict it manually, as shown below.

```
@Component
public class CacheManagerService {
  @CacheEvict("movies")
  public void evictMoviesFromCache(final String networkRef) {
    // nothing to add as this method is to evict the cache
  }
}
```

And Autowire CacheManagerService in your code and invoke the method explicitly. for e.g.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class MoviesCacheManager {
  private final CacheManagerService cacheManagerService;
  private final MoviesClient moviesClient;

public List<Location> refreshMovies() {
    cacheManagerService.evictMoviesFromCache();
    var movies = moviesClient.getMovies().collectList().block();
    return Optional.ofNullable(movies).orElse(emptyList());
  }
}
```

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial